# How can I run things off Netbeans on Ubuntu? Localhost not working

Tags: php, netbeans, ubuntu, localhost

When I try to run something on Netbeans using Ubuntu, a window opens but nothing actually works. I'm pretty sure it's because my http://localhost/ isn't working. So, how do I get that to work so I run files on Netbeans? Any specific step-by-step instructions would be great. I heard I had to install Apache, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi Dan, you might have to provide more information about what it is you're trying to run. I guess it is a web application of some kind. Is it a WAR?

Comment: Make sure the files you're trying to run are in your Apache DocumentRoot dir.

Comment: Hey guys, I'm trying to run .php and .html.inc files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run PHP stuff outside NetBeans, there are several steps you have to take:

1. Install apache web server - `sudo apt-get install apache2`
2. Install PHP and connect it with apache - `sudo apt-get install php5` `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`
3. Restart apache - `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Now, your Document Root (web root) should be at `/var/www`.
Place your files there and access them with `http://localhost/desired_file.php` with some web browser or just execute them with `php` compiler on the command line.

Depending on your distro/version, there might be some configurations to be done, but that's the basic stuff you need to run PHP outside NetBeans